# .NET MAUI Splashscreen Background is not changing

Tags: maui, android-splashscreen

Not sure if this could be a bug or what

If I set the splashscreen color it only works if the theme is Light. For the Dark theme it stays black. You see the image with a white background though. This is now for Android.

```xml
<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\logo.svg" Color="White" />
```

Updates to this question:

I have implemented the solution at

https://ewerspej.hashnode.dev/lets-customize-the-splash-screen-of-a-maui-app#heading-light-mode

It works for Light Mode as expected, but for Dark Mode the colorPrimaryDark is ignored. There is always this black frame around the logo. The logo's background is set to Transparent and still the logo has a background of White with the black frame around it.

I am doing this for Android (for now) and I am not using the Emulator but my Xioami Redmi Note 10 Pro. The device runs Android 12 and MIUI 13.016. All updated. The API is API 31 - Which I guess could be the issue.

I have also searched for any possibility of black and tried to change it. Problem still persist.

I would like the image and the background to be white in Dark or Light theme.

If I could just disable dark mode for the app that would be great.

Below a screenshot of what I see in Dark Mode.

[image]

Thanks!

Jaco

Comment: Which .NET version are you working with? Have you searched for other questions on the topic and did you check if an issue was reported in the [MAUI GitHub repository](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues)?

Comment: .NET 7. Searched extensively and checked GitHub but couldn't find the issue. Similar issues but not the one I am struggling with.

Comment: Can you please show more of your code in the question? Did you make any changes to the MainActivity.cs in the Android-specific folder? What changes did you make compared the default app template? Please also add a screenshot of what it looks like at the moment and describe how you would like it to look.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with a new MAUI app project, it works as expected - I get the same color for Dark and Light mode. Which Android version are you on? I know that the splash screen doesn't work properly with API 31, but more recent versions work fine.

Comment: Thanks. I have given more info in the question above. I guess the problem could be API 31. Not sure how to upgrade it

Comment: Why did you implement light and dark mode separately based on my blog post, if you want them both to look the same anyway? I believe you took the complicated path without reason. What I've shown in my blog post is useful, if you want to have a different background color based on the theme of the device's OS. What does your *MainActivity.cs* look like? I think you should stick with the default behavior of MAUI.

Comment: True. I was just desperate and then also at a later stage I will implement the Dark Mode if needed. Your previous comment actually answered the issue. It is API 31 which is the problem. I have installed my Samsung tablet with a higher API and the problem is solved. Much appreciated

Comment: Interesting that the problem persist for a Xioami Redmi Note 10 Pro but for other Android devices it seems to be solved with API Level 33

Comment: You may need to report this as an issue on the [MAUI GitHub repository](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).

Comment: Will definitely do so. Thanks.

Comment: @Systellence link the issue here if you don't mind

Comment: Not sure where you want me to link it. In the meantime I found out that when you force it to a light theme you should not specify white as a background color. Any other color works but not white. That is on my xiaomi

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Maui Splashscreen for the windows platform by using this method.

open the `Package.appxmanifest` file in the Platform->Windows folder. Then you can change the splashscreen for the Windows paltform.

Comment: The OP is asking specifically for Android.